# how can you install a KVM guest os in nographic mode

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, linux-kvm

I need to install a KVM guest OS but without the use of a GUI.
What I found so far:

create a disk image for the guest

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 vdisk.img 10G
```

install the guest OS

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda vdisk.img -cdrom /path/to/boot-media.iso \ 
   -boot d  -m 1024 -localtime -clock unix -nographic
```

Adding in the nographic paramater will disable the video output and I'll see nothing; I would have expected some output to be redirected to the console, but I get nothing.

I tried replacing `-nographic` with `-curses` but that did not help either.

So the question stands: can you install an guess OS in kvm without a GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eventually I figured it out; It can be done using a vnc connection. Use the following options:

```
-nographic -vnc your_server_ip:1 -k en-us
```

This will start a vnc server to which you can connect from another machine using a vnc client.

Answer (score 0):

sudo mount -o loop image.iso tmp/ This step will mount the disk image to a tmp directory.
copy the vmlinuz and initrd inside tmp to a directory. You may use the find command to search the paths of files. The file location depends on the distribution. For example, for ubuntu 19.10 the path are tmp/casper/initrd and tmp/casper/vmlinuz.
add
-nographic
-append console=ttyS0 \
-kernel path/to/vmlinuz \
-initrd path/to/initrd
to the qemu command, and then you can install the vm with command text only.

Hope this helps.